# File with saved states in vim

Tags: plugins, vim

I'd like to create a file and edit it with `vim` editor,

then save a file and after saving a file always have a possibility
to decide that this is a `State X` (where X = 1, 2, 3, ...) of my editing work.

When I open the file later, I'd like to use commands like

`gotostate 7`

to see the file in state 7.

That's all.

Is there such a plugin or other possibility for the `vim` editor?

I try to avoid using `git` or other `source control` tools, because I only
need these two quick features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my [histwin](https://github.com/chrisbra/histwin.vim) plugin. It can tag certain undo states and go back to them if needed.